# Do table names always have to be in front of fields when using sql joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a query:

```
select 
    Last_Name, 
    First_Name, 
    e.EmployeeID
from 
    employee e
join 
    Employee_his eh on e.EmployeeID = eh.EmployeeID
```

First name and Last name are part of the employee table while `employeeId` is part of both.

Does adding the table alias `e` in front of `last_name`, `first_name` alter the statement in any way? I thought not but am told it will give me the wrong answer. Sorry about the simple question, it's a hard thing to look up.

Comment: as far as i am aware it wont make a difference, as long as there isnt a `Last_Name` or `First_Name` column in the other table otherwise without the `e` the call would be ambiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select Last_Name, First_Name, e.EmployeeID
from employee e join
     Employee_his eh
     on e.EmployeeID = eh.EmployeeID;
```

In this case, the qualified names are needed, because `EmployeeId` --
 with no qualification -- would be ambiguous.  Which table would the column be referring to?

When you have multiple tables in a query, you should qualify all column names, so it is clear what the query is doing -- for others reading the query and for you months later.

I should note that ANSI SQL has the `using` clause.  In many databases, the query could be written as:

```
select Last_Name, First_Name, EmployeeID
from employee e join
     Employee_his eh
     using (EmployeeId);
```

However, SQL Server does not support the `using` clause.

Comment: I was told not putting the alias in would give me different answers. Just to be clear, it's a coding convention that helps make the code clearer later down the line yes? Leaving the alias/table name out(where the field only exists in one table) wont change the query in any way will it?

Comment: @JohnDoh . . . There are very few cases where queries would return different results with the aliases.  The issue would typically be syntax errors.

Comment: Sorry, one last thing. Does adding the alias/tables name do anything for performance? good or bad?

Comment: There will not be any differences with the aliases.  There is a nearly immeasurable boost to performance because the optimizer doesn't need to determine which column the table comes from, same as qualifying the table schema name, but I would not consider performance to be a reason to qualify the column name.

Comment: You should always qualify all columns when tables are joined.  The saving on troubleshooting and extending code later can be significant.  For example, if you add another table that has a Last_Name column, you'd have to go back and qualify the existing Last_Name column.  That wouldn't be to hard in a simple query, but queries tend to grow over time or be used as the basis for more complex queries.  Also, when you get a column based error, it takes longer to identify the source table for the column when it is not qualified.  That makes troubleshooting frustrating, especially after hours.

Answer (score 0):

If both tables have a field with the same name, then yes, you need to have the table name or an alias in front of the field name.

Comment: Or a *table alias* as in this case